# How to rewrite URL using .htaccess in WordPress Plugin

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, htaccess

I want to rewrite URL as Following. How do i use htaccess in plugin.

`http://localhost/IDU/collections/?cid=10`

to

`http://localhost/IDU/collections/10`

Comment: Hello Can you explain what is collections is it Custom post type or category?

Comment: You shouldn't use htaccess for rewriting URLs in a plugin, it won't work on NGINX based servers, a WP rewrite rule is the way to go here

Comment: Collections is just a page in wordpress. @Pratik bhatt

Comment: If is just page the what parameters are you passing into cid?

Comment: in cid in have category_id of my plugin table, and in this page i have a shortcode to show products according to category